# Why does Ruby include? function not working as expected with AngularJS variable?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

In the haml of my Ruby on Rails app I'm trying to get through an array via AngularJS's `ng-repeat` and only display the strings of this array that are contained in another array. I'm trying to achieve this with the help of the `include?` function of Ruby to know if each string is in my other array but it returns false even if the string is in my other array.

Here's my code to debug this problem (with in comment my "real" code):

```
 %span.badge{"ng-repeat" => "competence_name in mymodel.get_competence_names track by $index"}
     = "{{competence_name}}"
     = current_user.get_competence_names
     = current_user.get_competence_names.include?("{{competence_name}}")
     -#- if current_user.get_competence_names.include?("{{competence_name}}")
         -#= "{{ competence_name }}"
```

This code displays:

```
Challenger ["Challenger", "Creative", "Innovative", "Results-oriented"] false
```

Note that at the end of the line include? is supposed to return `true` and not `false` as "Challenger" is included in the array.

But if I replace this line:

```
= current_user.get_competence_names.include?("{{competence_name}}")
```

By this line:

```
= current_user.get_competence_names.include?("Challenger")
```

It displays `true` instead of `false`

So I was thinking that it was a type problem and that `"{{ competence_name }}"` was not interpreted as a `String` by Ruby. So I tried to replace `"{{ competence_name }}"` by `String.new("{{ competence_name }}")` but it's still returning false...

Do you have any idea of the source of the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do you have any idea of the source of the problem?

Yes. When ruby runs, angular is not yet bootstrapped and didn't have a chance to process the bindings. This means that string `"{{competence_name}}"` is just that, a literal string `"{{competence_name}}"`. Of course, it's not in the list.

Similarly, when JS runs, ruby code is long finished. In fact, there's no ruby code at all there (in the context where JS runs).

Client-side and server-side don't mix.

Comment: Thank's for your precisions, I see way clearer now. I'll rethink my code logic.